# Rblpapi - bdh function returns NULL with certain fields

Tags: r, bloomberg

Does `bdh()` only work with certain Bloomberg fields on Rblpapi? The following returns NULL:

```
library(Rblpapi)
blpConnect()
bdh("IBM US Equity", "RR906", start.date = Sys.Date()-22)
```

and so does using the mnemonic for the field:

```
bdh("IBM US Equity", "TRAIL_12M_EPS", start.date = Sys.Date()-22)
```

I can get the current value through `bdp()` but that's it. `bdh()` seems to be working fine for Real-time fields but not so for Static ones even though Bloomberg says historical values are available for those through the API.

Has anyone run into this problem? And more importantly, are there any solutions for this? Not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT:
I figured out a solution. Using the following option returns the correct values:

```
bdh("IBM Equity", "TRAIL_12M_EPS", Sys.Date()-22, options = c("nonTradingDayFillOption"="ALL_CALENDAR_DAYS"))
```

Depending on user requirements the value of `nonTradingDayFillOption` can also be set to `ACTIVE_DAYS_ONLY` (returns only days when field value changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following option returns the correct values:

```
bdh("IBM Equity", "TRAIL_12M_EPS", Sys.Date()-22, options = c("nonTradingDayFillOption"="ALL_CALENDAR_DAYS"))
```

Depending on user requirements the value of nonTradingDayFillOption can also be set to ACTIVE_DAYS_ONLY (returns only days when field value changes).

Going through the full [API documentation](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/content/uploads/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf) does help, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Basically the error here is that you used "IBM Equity" where it should be "IBM US Equity"
Best regards,

Comment: can you expand this answer a little more?

Comment: That was not the error in the case. You're fine not providing the exchange code and it assumes you want the terminal's primary exchange. You can easily test this in all Bloomberg API implementations. The cause was specified in the answer above.